# How do I change the text of multiple elements with the same name in elementtree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

So I have an XML which has a line:

```
<factor-apply>1.2</factor-apply>
```

**And this line is in my XML twice.**

I would like to change the text **for both lines** such that they **both** change to:

```
<factor-apply>0.5</factor-apply>
```

My code is as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_tree = ET.parse(TestXML.xml)
root = xml_tree.getroot()
root.find(".//{*}factor-apply").text = "0.5" 
ET.tostring(root)
```

Now this changes the first factor line in my XML but not the second.

I tried to do

```
root.findall(".//{*}factor-apply").text = "0.5"
```

but I get the error message

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5072\1499665917.py in <module>
      3 xml_tree = ET.parse(TestXML.xml)
      4 root = xml_tree.getroot()
----> 5 root.findall(".//{*}factor-apply").text = "0.5" 
      6 ET.tostring(root)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I'm wondering if I would have to make a loop in order to this as findall isn't working??
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I would like to be able to do this for any variable. So I have a line which corresponds to date of birth. But that line is there 10 times so I would want to change all 10 lines for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
for factor in root.findall(".//{*}factor"):
     factor.text = "0.5"
```

and see if it works. If it does, you can probably replace `factor` with any other element name.

Comment: Hey sorry, I just edited my code but it should be factor-apply. Not factor and because factor-apply has a hyphen it won't work as it thinks the hyphen is a minus

Comment: @Mark That shouldn't make any difference, so there must be something else going on. Can you edit your question and add the actual (or representative sample of your) xml?

Comment: When I try to apply your code I get the following error:
` for factor-apply in root.findall(".//{*}factor-apply"):
        ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
`

Comment: @Mark Try changing the name of your variable in the loop; for example, instead of  `for factor-apply in root.findall...` use something like `for fa in root.findall...`

Comment: That works Thank you!

Comment: @Mark Glad it worked for you!